# How to properly exit from service process written in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I need to make a service using .NET. I implement ServiceBase, override OnStart and OnStop methods, and everything works correctly except that if I put this code into OnStop:

```
protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

then when I'm stopping the service I'm getting Error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly.
If I don't include `Environment.Exit(0);`, then the process is never terminated and just keeps working even if the service was stopped.
It's not so critical and the service works as it should, but still it would be nice if there was a way to get rid of that error.

Comment: What is the code in the OnStart override?

Comment: This might help https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2017/september/clean-stop-of-windows-service-in-net/